# retrofit Android upload video

Tags: php, android, retrofit

I m using Retrofit to upload images to my server 
the Upload is working fine 
but when the image size is a bit big its throws an exception

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

Here my code

```
public interface RestClient {
@Multipart
@POST("/upload2.php")
Response uploadUserIds(@Part("photo") TypedFile photo);
 }

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(UploadFiles.SERVER_URL)
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC)
        .setLog(new RestAdapter.Log() {
            @Override
            public void log(String msg) {
                Log.i(TAG, msg);
            }
        })
        .build();

RestClient service = restAdapter.create(RestClient.class);
```

//My call

```
Response tr = service.uploadUserIds(new TypedFile(typeFile, f));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily an issue in the client side. I strongly beleive that the file size is more than maxUpload Size allowed by server.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem as well. I was using Retrofit within an Android client on the emulator and trying to upload (fairly small) test video files to my server code running within Eclipse on my Windows PC. I set up Retrofit for full logging using:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("http://10.0.2.2:8080")
        .setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)
        .build();
```

This consistently caused the error above when trying to upload certain files.
However, when I set the log level to basic using `setLogLevel(LogLevel.BASIC)` then all those files started being uploaded ok.

So I suspect that this might be some sort of internal Retrofit error, maybe associated with buffers overflowing. I don't think it's a server problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the issue on the server side . Script might be getting stuck somewhere in the code, hence not posting the response meanwhile server would have closed the socket. There could be two solutions to this:

1. Resolving the issues in server side script

Second one is not preferable :

2. Increasing timeout values to a large number at the client side !!

Hope this helps